# Subclassing UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I would like to create my own subclass of `UIImage` that would allow me to create a realizable/stretchable image with caps on each of the four sides.

iOS 5's `resizableImage` does not fit my needs since it does not allow me to stretch the middle part, neither does the now deprecated `stretchableImage` because it allows me to repeat only a single pixel, while I may want to repeat some sort of gradient.

So far everything works fine, I implemented my own drawing code in `-drawInRect:` and it behaves as expected.
However, when assigning my custom subclass instance as a `UIImageView`'s image, my code breaks. The image gets rendered as the normal UIImage would. (scaled in all directions without any caps)

I tried to set breakpoints at all of the four drawing methods (`drawInRect`, `drawAtPoint`, both standalone plus with `blendMode:` but they seem not to get called.

Is there a way to provide a `UIImage` with custom drawing code when using it within a `UIImageView` without subclassing `UIImageView`, too?

Also, I am worrying about performance. The default stretchable image works quite well during animations, but I wonder how it'd be when animating size properties (width & height) of my `UIImageView`. Would my rendering code get called every frame?

Comment: Why not just write your own UIView subclass instead of using UIImageView? You can use your UIImage subclass or even a CGImageRef instead.

Comment: I know that I could do that, but say I have a large project with many stretchable images that would break when it is no longer supported. I simply want to change the call to make it stretchable while preserving the rest of the code. I don't want to replace every single UIImageView with my own UIView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it clearly says you can't override `-drawRect:` of a `UIImageView`, so subclassing `UIImageView` will not work also. You have to implement your own `UIView` class.

Subclassing `UIImage` will neither work, I have tried this and no public method was called at all, not even the accessory method for `CGImage`. I think you would need to override some private API to make this work.

Don't worry about resizing, your rendering code will only be called for the final frame. 
Still, in most cases performance is worse than using an `UIImageView`. Apple optimized the class so it runs on the GPU.

Comment: How can the animation run smoothly when I only 'render' the last frame? Say I have a cap on the left and on the right side, and want to make the view 100px wider. The center part should resize and the right cap move to the right. Is this really possible with `-drawRect:` getting called only once?